# Python3 CGI: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python-3.x, forms, cgi

I wonder if this is a bug in Python 3.09/3.10 (I haven't tested this on 3.11, since miniconda still does not support it yet).

The following gives me an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'.

Here's "test.html":

```
<html><body>
<form name="Form" method="POST" action="/cgi-bin/test.cgi">
<input type="file" id="file_f" name="data"><br>
<input id="button" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="button">
</form>
</body></html>
```

... and here's "test.cgi", receiving the request above:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable(display=1)

print('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n')

html_body = """
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>{}</body></html>
"""

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
fileitem = form['data']
fbuf = fileitem.file.read()

print(html_body.format(fbuf))
```

Your opinion is much appreciated. Thanks!

- form.getvalue('data') works (i.e., grabs text in the entryfield as-is)
- Just throwing "fileitem.file.read()" triggers this same AttributeError.
- "fileitem.file.readline()" is not recognised as well.
- Tried this on both Python 3.09 and 3.10, and both give the same error.